# Creating Different Dataframe for conditions on multiple column in Excel using Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I want to make a different dataframe for those `Number(Column B)` where *Main Date* > *Reported Date* (see the below image). If this condition comes true then I have to make other dataframe displaying that Number Data.

Example

```
:- if take Number (column B) 223311, now if any main date > Reported Date, then display all the records of that Number
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution with Pandas. You can separate out Dataframes very easily by column values of a particular column. From there, iterate the new Dataframe, resetting for index (if you want to keep the index, use dataframe.shape instead). I appended them to a list for convenience, which could be easily extracted into labeled dataframes, or combined. Long variable names are to help comprehension.

```
df = pd.read_csv('forstack.csv')
list_of_dataframes = [] #A place to store each dataframe. You could also name them as you go
checked_Numbers = [] #Simply to avoid multiple of same dataframe

for aNumber in df['Number']: #For every number in the column "Number"
    if(aNumber not in checked_Numbers): #While this number has not been processed
        checked_Numbers.append(aNumber) #Mark as checked
        df_forThisNumber = df[df.Number == aNumber].reset_index(drop=True) #"Make a different Dataframe" Per request, with new index
        for index in range(0,len(df_forThisNumber)): #Parse each element of this dataframe to see if it matches criteria
            if(df_forThisNumber.at[index,'Main Date'] > df_forThisNumber.at[index,'Reported Date']):
                list_of_dataframes.append(df_forThisNumber) #If it matches the criteria, append it
```

Outputs :

```
  Main Date  Number Reported Date  Fee  Amount  Cost  Name
0  1/1/2019  223311      1/1/2019  100      12    20    11
1  1/7/2019  223311      1/1/2019  100      12    20    11
  Main Date  Number Reported Date  Fee  Amount  Cost  Name
0  1/2/2019  111111      1/2/2019  100      12    20    11
1  1/6/2019  111111      1/2/2019  100      12    20    11
  Main Date  Number Reported Date  Fee  Amount  Cost  Name
0  1/3/2019  222222      1/3/2019  100      12    20    11
1  1/8/2019  222222      1/3/2019  100      12    20    11
```

Comment: Now m facing this error :- raise ValueError("Unknown string format:", timestr)

ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '\\N')